# Is it possible to to remap the "POS1" (Arrow up) key from the Magic Keyboard permanently and system wide to "Beginning of the Line"?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I am a developer and would like that button to go to the beginning of the line (please do not recommend any "pressX+Y(+Z)" finger gymnastics).

##### Update 1

I would like to make it as native in the OS as possible. Ideally no 3rd party tool installations

**Any way to achieve the question asked?**

Comment: What's going to happen when you just want to go up one line rather than the beginning of the line? That's why the standard shortcuts have modifiers. How does being a developer make it any different?

Comment: There are [*tons* of existing questions/answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Remap+keys) on remapping keys.  What have you tried thus far?  What *specific* issue are you experiencing with those solutions?

Comment: Updated the question. Ideally no 3rd party installations. Being a developer you will quickly realise what the inconvenience is.